# FC and Main Thread terminate. Source not found

Tags: android, android-intent, runtime-error

I have an app with 3 activities, first the splash screen, second the main activity screen, and third a GPS location activity. From the main activity screen, I call to the GPS location activity to retrieve latitude and longitude through a intent. If I check the 3rd activity like an app, it works fine. But I put it as an activity and I have the next errors.

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8613]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(IBinder, boolean) line: not available  
        ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(IBinder, boolean, boolean) line: not available  
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: not available    
        ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: not available  
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: not available 
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: not available  
        Looper.loop() line: not available   
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: not available   
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: not available    
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: not available    
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: not available   
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
    Thread [<11> Binder_3] (Running)    
    Thread [<12> AsyncTask #1] (Running)
```

This is the Asynctask method with which I call to the 3rd activity.

```
private class getLocationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        /**
         * El sistema llama a este método para realizar el trabajo en un hilo
         * trabajador y le entrega los parámetros dados a AsyncTask.execute()
         */
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // In the method that is called when click on "update". Go to the 2
            // activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    getLocationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0); // 0 is a detectable code
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }

    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

getLocationCode

```
package victor.martin.noow;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class getLocationActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private TextView mLatLng;
    private TextView mAddress;
    private Button mFineProviderButton;
    private Button mBothProviderButton;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean mGeocoderAvailable;
    private boolean mUseFine;
    private boolean mUseBoth;

    private double latitude, longitude;
    private String street;

    // Keys for maintaining UI states after rotation.
    private static final String KEY_FINE = "use_fine";
    private static final String KEY_BOTH = "use_both";
    // UI handler codes.
    private static final int UPDATE_ADDRESS = 1;
    private static final int UPDATE_LATLNG = 2;

    private static final int TEN_SECONDS = 10000;
    private static final int TEN_METERS = 10;
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;

    /**
     * This sample demonstrates how to incorporate location based services in
     * your app and process location updates. The app also shows how to convert
     * lat/long coordinates to human-readable addresses.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.location_layout);

        // Restore apps state (if exists) after rotation.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mUseFine = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_FINE);
            mUseBoth = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_BOTH);
        } else {
            mUseFine = false;
            mUseBoth = false;
        }
        mLatLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlng);
        mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
        // Receive location updates from the fine location provider (gps) only.
        //mFineProviderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.provider_fine);
        // Receive location updates from both the fine (gps) and coarse
        // (network) location
        // providers.
        //mBothProviderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.provider_both);

        // The isPresent() helper method is only available on Gingerbread or
        // above.
        mGeocoderAvailable = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD
                && Geocoder.isPresent();

        // Handler for updating text fields on the UI like the lat/long and
        // address.
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case UPDATE_ADDRESS:
                    //mAddress.setText((String) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case UPDATE_LATLNG:
                    //mLatLng.setText((String) msg.obj);
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        // Get a reference to the LocationManager object.
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    // Restores UI states after rotation.
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_FINE, mUseFine);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_BOTH, mUseBoth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Check if the GPS setting is currently enabled on the device.
        // This verification should be done during onStart() because the system
        // calls this method
        // when the user returns to the activity, which ensures the desired
        // location provider is
        // enabled each time the activity resumes from the stopped state.
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!gpsEnabled) {
            // Build an alert dialog here that requests that the user enable
            // the location services, then when the user clicks the "OK" button,
            // call enableLocationSettings()
            new EnableGpsDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "enableGpsDialog");
        }
    }

    // Method to launch Settings
    private void enableLocationSettings() {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(
                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }

    // Stop receiving location updates whenever the Activity becomes invisible.
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    // Set up fine and/or coarse location providers depending on whether the
    // fine provider or
    // both providers button is pressed.
    private void setup() {
        Location gpsLocation = null;
        Location networkLocation = null;
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        mLatLng.setText(R.string.unknown);
        mAddress.setText(R.string.unknown);
        // Get fine location updates only.
        if (mUseFine) {
            //mFineProviderButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_active);
            //mBothProviderButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_inactive);
            // Request updates from just the fine (gps) provider.
            gpsLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, R.string.not_support_gps);
            // Update the UI immediately if a location is obtained.
            if (gpsLocation != null)
                updateUILocation(gpsLocation);
        } else if (mUseBoth) {
            // Get coarse and fine location updates.
            //mFineProviderButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_inactive);
            //mBothProviderButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_active);
            // Request updates from both fine (gps) and coarse (network)
            // providers.
            gpsLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, R.string.not_support_gps);
            networkLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    R.string.not_support_network);

            // If both providers return last known locations, compare the two
            // and use the better
            // one to update the UI. If only one provider returns a location,
            // use it.
            if (gpsLocation != null && networkLocation != null) {
                updateUILocation(getBetterLocation(gpsLocation, networkLocation));
            } else if (gpsLocation != null) {
                updateUILocation(gpsLocation);
            } else if (networkLocation != null) {
                updateUILocation(networkLocation);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to register location updates with a desired location provider. If
     * the requested provider is not available on the device, the app displays a
     * Toast with a message referenced by a resource id.
     * 
     * @param provider
     *            Name of the requested provider.
     * @param errorResId
     *            Resource id for the string message to be displayed if the
     *            provider does not exist on the device.
     * @return A previously returned {@link android.location.Location} from the
     *         requested provider, if exists.
     */
    private Location requestUpdatesFromProvider(final String provider,
            final int errorResId) {
        Location location = null;
        if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TEN_SECONDS,
                    TEN_METERS, listener);
            location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, errorResId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return location;
    }

    // Callback method for the "fine provider" button.
    public void useFineProvider(View v) {
        mUseFine = true;
        mUseBoth = false;
        setup();
    }

    // Callback method for the "both providers" button.
    public void useCoarseFineProviders(View v) {
        mUseFine = false;
        mUseBoth = true;
        setup();
    }

    private void doReverseGeocoding(Location location) {
        // Since the geocoding API is synchronous and may take a while. You
        // don't want to lock
        // up the UI thread. Invoking reverse geocoding in an AsyncTask.
        (new ReverseGeocodingTask(this)).execute(new Location[] { location });
    }

    private void updateUILocation(Location location) {
        // We're sending the update to a handler which then updates the UI with
        // the new
        // location.
        Message.obtain(mHandler, UPDATE_LATLNG,
                location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude())
                .sendToTarget();

        // Bypass reverse-geocoding only if the Geocoder service is available on
        // the device.
        if (mGeocoderAvailable)
            doReverseGeocoding(location);
    }

    private final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // A new location update is received. Do something useful with it.
            // Update the UI with
            // the location update.
            updateUILocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    /**
     * Determines whether one Location reading is better than the current
     * Location fix. Code taken from
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location
     * /obtaining-user-location.html
     * 
     * @param newLocation
     *            The new Location that you want to evaluate
     * @param currentBestLocation
     *            The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new
     *            one
     * @return The better Location object based on recency and accuracy.
     */
    protected Location getBetterLocation(Location newLocation,
            Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return newLocation;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = newLocation.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use
        // the new location
        // because the user has likely moved.
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return newLocation;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be
            // worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return currentBestLocation;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (newLocation.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation
                .getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(newLocation.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and
        // accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return newLocation;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return newLocation;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate
                && isFromSameProvider) {
            return newLocation;
        }
        return currentBestLocation;
    }

    /** Checks whether two providers are the same */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    // AsyncTask encapsulating the reverse-geocoding API. Since the geocoder API
    // is blocked,
    // we do not want to invoke it from the UI thread.
    private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, Void> {
        Context mContext;

        public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Location... params) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());

            Location loc = params[0];
            List<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                mUseFine = false;
                mUseBoth = true;
                setup();
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                        loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                longitude = loc.getLongitude();

                Log.i("GETLOC-INFO", ">>>>" + latitude + " / " + longitude);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Update address field with the exception.
                Message.obtain(mHandler, UPDATE_ADDRESS, e.toString())
                        .sendToTarget();
            }
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                // Format the first line of address (if available), city, and
                // country name.
                String addressText = String.format(
                        "%s, %s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                                .getAddressLine(0) : "", address.getLocality(),
                        address.getCountryName());
                street = addressText;
                // Update address field on UI.
                Message.obtain(mHandler, UPDATE_ADDRESS, addressText)
                        .sendToTarget();
            }

            if (latitude != 0.0) { // We got data

                // Send the data to the Main Activity
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
                data.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
                data.putExtra("street", street);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Dialog to prompt users to enable GPS on the device.
     */
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    private class EnableGpsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(R.string.enable_gps)
                    .setMessage(R.string.enable_gps_dialog)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.enable_gps,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    enableLocationSettings();
                                }
                            }).create();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the code from the Android Developers Guide -> LocationAware Example. It had 2 buttons to call 2 different methods to get location. I change some piece of code to make that at the start of the activity, starts to get the location.

Comment: Error seems to be in getLocationActivity class. please share code for that

Comment: Added the source code. Thanks.

Comment: my best guess is that your UI is not initialized properly and its failing somewhere, debugging your resume code might help

Comment: Ok, I will continue debugging.